# Magento 2: "Memory limit has been reached" when resizing images

Tags: magento-2.1

After migrating from **Magento 1.7.0.2** to **Magento 2.1.7** I needed to resize images. I did with

```
php_cli bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

That throws an exception "Memory limit has been reached" after a while. Studying the web I found that GD2.php is responsible for image manipulation. And I found a hint, that in earlier versions of Magento there was a problem with PHP-cli limit set to -1. But that seem to be fixed in **GD2.php** of Magento 2.

But where comes the error in Magento 2 from? Can someone explain that to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
php -dmemory_limit = 500G bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```